# Acting upon the result of two asynchronous function calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I want to make a form submission if, and only if, two calls to asynchronous functions return false.

This is simplified code:

```
var firstConfirmed = false;
var secondConfirmed = false;

$form.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!firstConfirmed) {
        firstConfirmed = getConfirmation1();    
    }

    if (!secondConfirmed) {
        secondConfirmed = getConfirmation2()
    }

    **if (firstConfirmed && secondConfirmed) { // This will get evaluated before the asynchronous calls finish :(
        $form.submit();
    }

});
```

`getConfirmation1()` and `getConfirmation2()` are asynchronous:

```
var getConfirmation1 = function() {
    bootbox.confirm('Are you sure?', function(result) {
        if (result) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
};
```

(the `bootbox` plugin just waits for the user input - confirm/cancel, the same goes for `getConfirmation2()`)

The problem is that the conditional marked with `**` will be evaluated right away so there is no chance for the form submission to ever take place. How can I solve this problem and submit the form once both - `getConfirmation1()` and `getConfirmation2()` return `true` ?

Comment: I wonder if promises are supported for whatever library you have? If so, the answer is decently trivial: `Promise.all([getPromiseOfConfirmation1(), getPromiseOfConfirmation2()]).then(function() {$form.submit()$})` or assuming you're in an `async function` you could also use `await Promise.all([getPromiseOfConfirmation1(), getPromiseOfConfirmation2()]); $form.submit()`.

Comment: I'm going too far into the future.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either set a timer that periodically recalls the submit function, or you could call the submit function again from your confirmation dialogs after they are confirmed.

actually, i'm not even sure your code is doing what you think it is doing.

firstConfirmed and secondConfirmed never get set because of the asynchronous nature.  You need variables that are outside of the scope of the submit function that can be set by the confirmation dialogs.

Then you would set them explicitly in your dialogs

```
if (result) {
    firstConfirmed = true;
    doSubmitAgain();
}
```

Comment: `firstConfirmed` and `secondConfirmed` are both set to `false` by default outside of the `submit()` function. However, I think that the idea of calling `submit()` again form the dialogue will sort the problem out - it'd rely on monitoring the state of `firstConfirmed` and `secondConfirmed` so, upon the second call to `submit()` and a second confirmation, the actual submission should take place (both `firstConfirmed` and `secondConfirmed` would then evaluate to `true`). Thanks for help. I'll be able to test it tomorrow :)

Answer (score 2):

You could specify a callback function that you pass into your asynchronous functions like this:

```
var getConfirmation1 = function(callback) {
  bootbox.confirm('Are you sure?', function(result) {
    return callback(!!result);
  });
};
```

...and then define that callback function like so:

```
var firstConfirmed = false;
var secondConfirmed = false;

$form.submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  getConfirmation1(function (isConfirmed) {
    // Callback function for getConfirmation1
    firstConfirmed = isConfirmed
    checkConfirmed()
  })
  getConfirmation2(function (isConfirmed) {
    // Callback function for getConfirmation2
    secondConfirmed = isConfirmed
    checkConfirmed()
  })
});

function checkConfirmed () {
  // Return if either async function has not confirmed
  if (!firstConfirmed || !secondConfirmed) {
    return
  }
  // Both confirmed!
  $form.submit();
}
```

---

---

Alternatively, your specific example could be further simplified by not wrapping the bootbox call like so:

```
var firstConfirmed = false;
var secondConfirmed = false;

$form.submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  bootbox.confirm('Are you sure?', function(result) {
    // Callback function for first bootbox dialog
    firstConfirmed = !!result
    checkConfirmed()
  })
  bootbox.confirm('Are you sure?', function(result) {
    // Callback function for second bootbox dialog
    secondConfirmed = !!result
    checkConfirmed()
  })
});

function checkConfirmed () {
  // Return if either async function has not confirmed
  if (!firstConfirmed || !secondConfirmed) {
    return
  }
  // Both confirmed!
  $form.submit();
}
```